# Is it possible to style a href widget differently in UiApp?

Tags: google-apps-script

In UiApp, the default style for href widgets is the classical blue underlined aspect.
Is it possible to define a new style for this like one can do with css style sheets and html ?

For example : link in normal black, getting grey when hovering ?

here is how I did it in css :

```
h1 a:link, h1 a:active, h1 a:visited {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1 span {
    color: #111;
}
h1 a:hover, h1 a:focus {
    color: #777;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the primary style via `setStyleAttributes` but you cannot set pseudo-selector styles like hover and focus.

Comment: Thank you Corey, that's what I was afraid of... Could I do that using html service ?

Comment: Yup. HtmlService supports all of the pseudo-selectors.

Comment: I'll have to "update" myself to this one of these days :) thanks